# MSE loss different in Keras and PyToch

Tags: keras, loss-function, pytorch

My problem is that in PyTorch I cannot reproduce the MSE loss that I have achieved in Keras.

I have trained the following model in Keras:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "mean_squared_error")
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
      batch_size = 32,
      epochs = 200
     )
```

The shape of the training data is:

```
print(X_train.shape)
>>>(3550, 10)
print(y_train.shape)
>>>(3550,)
```

After training the MSE is ~0.15:

```
mse_train = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
>>>3550/3550 [==============================] - 0s 18us/step
print("Train MSE: ", mse_train)
>>>Train MSE:  0.1499910642017781
```

Then I initialize the same model in PyTorch:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class NN(nn.Module):
 def __init__(self):
  super(NN, self).__init__()
  self.dense1 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
  self.dense2 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

 def forward(self, x):
  out = self.dense1(x)
  out = self.dense2(out)
  return out

net = NN()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
```

And assign the weights I have achieved in Keras:

```
from keras.models import load_model
keras_model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)

dense_weights = keras_model.layers[0].get_weights()
weights = torch.tensor(dense_weights[0].swapaxes(0,1))
bias = torch.tensor(dense_weights[1])
net.dense1.weight.data = weights
net.dense1.bias.data = bias

dense_weights = keras_model.layers[1].get_weights()
weights = torch.tensor(dense_weights[0].swapaxes(0,1))
bias = torch.tensor(dense_weights[1])
net.dense2.weight.data = weights
net.dense2.bias.data = bias
```

Now I try to calculate the MSE loss:

```
X_train_torch = torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float)
y_train_torch = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.float)

outputs = net(X_train_torch)
loss = criterion(outputs, y_train_torch)
print("Train loss: ", loss)
>>>Train loss:  0.338391376896338
```

The MSE is now ~0.34 and is twice as big as calculated in Keras.

What could be the reason? Is there a bug in my calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `outputs` and `y_train_torch` had different shapes.